# Unable to get regex to capture last group

Tags: python, regex, bioinformatics

I'm trying to write a regex in python to parse a Newick tree, but for the life of me I can't get the last part of it to match. There are three types of Newick formats I need to parse:

```
((A,B),C);
((A:0.1,B:0.2),C:0.3);
((A:[c1]0.1,B:[c2]0.2),C:[c2]0.3);
```

...each of which contains three labels (A, B, C) and various other bits of information. I want to get the three labels. Here's my regex:

```
regex = re.compile(r"""
(
    ([,(])              # boundary
    ([A-Z0-9_\-\.]+)    # label
    (:)?                # optional colon
    (\[.+?\])?          # optional comment chunk
    (\d+\.\d+)?         # optional branchlengths
    ([),])              # end!
)
""", re.IGNORECASE + re.VERBOSE + re.DOTALL)
```

... however, I only get A and C. Not ever B. I've tracked the glitch down to the last captured group ([),]) - if I remove this, then I get all A, B, and C. Please help - what's going wrong here?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're looking for *non-overlapping* instances of the regex.
Methods like `findall` won't return B as the match for A consumes the `,` before `B`.

```
>>> regex.findall("((A:[c1]0.1,B:[c2]0.2),C:[c2]0.3);")
[('(A:[c1]0.1,', '(', 'A', ':', '[c1]', '0.1', ','), (',C:[c2]0.3)', ',', 'C', ':', '[c2]', '0.3', ')')]
```

Changing the end pattern to look ahead (so that it doesn't consume anything) solves the problem.

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"""
... (
...     ([,(])              # boundary
...     ([A-Z0-9_\-\.]+)    # label
...     (:)?                # optional colon
...     (\[.+?\])?          # optional comment chunk
...     (\d+\.\d+)?         # optional branchlengths
...     (?=[),])            # end!
... )
... """, re.IGNORECASE + re.VERBOSE + re.DOTALL)
>>>
>>> regex.findall("((A:[c1]0.1,B:[c2]0.2),C:[c2]0.3);")
[('(A:[c1]0.1', '(', 'A', ':', '[c1]', '0.1'), (',B:[c2]0.2', ',', 'B', ':', '[c2]', '0.2'), (',C:[c2]0.3', ',', 'C', ':
', '[c2]', '0.3')]
>>>
```

Otherwise, instead of using `findall`, you can use `search` iteratively and monkey with the `pos` argument.

Something like this:

```
>>> x = "((A:[c1]0.1,B:[c2]0.2),C:[c2]0.3);"
>>> r = []
>>> index = 0
>>> while True:
...     m = regex.search(x, index)
...     if not m:
...        break
...     r.append(m.groups())
...     index = m.end(7)-1
...
>>> r
[('(A:[c1]0.1,', '(', 'A', ':', '[c1]', '0.1', ','), (',B:[c2]0.2)', ',', 'B', ':', '[c2]', '0.2', ')'), (',C:[c2]0.3)',
 ',', 'C', ':', '[c2]', '0.3', ')')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the labels, couldn't you just use a simple regex like `[(,]([A-Z])`?

```
import re

text = ["((A,B),C);",
        "((A:0.1,B:0.2),C:0.3);",
        "((A:[c1]0.1,B:[c2]0.2),C:[c2]0.3);"]

for line in text:
    labels = re.findall(r'[(,]([A-Z])', line)
    print labels
```

**Result:**

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: I want to get the **whole** chunk (from the start boundary to the end boundary), and parse it into those subsections (start, label, comment, branchlengths, end) at the same time.